# Ruby: configuration file parser combined with OptionParser

Tags: ruby, parsing, configuration

I've got a script utilizing OptionParser and I want to add config file for the program which will have `option = value` format and `# comments`. Is there any way to make OptionParser parse files or some class able to use OptionParser rules and switches for config files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no built-in support for what you ask, but it's understandable because it would be so many ways to accomplish it. I'd use a default_options hash + YAML config file:

```
default_options = {
  :name => nil,
  :verbose => false,
}

options = default_options
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"
  opts.on("-v", "--verbose", "Run verbosely") do
    options[:verbose] = true
  end
  opts.on("-n", "--name NAME", "Set name") do |name|
    options[:name] = name
  end
  opts.on("-f", "--configfile PATH", String, "Set config file") do |path|
    options.merge!(Hash[YAML::load(open(path)).map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }])
  end
end.parse!
p options
```

Example of config YAML:

```
# config.yml
verbose: true
name: name_fromconf
```

And this is the result (example with override):

```
$ ruby example.rb -f config.yml -n "hello"
{:name=>"hello", :verbose=>true}
```

Comment: xyz.rb --some-option=X --another-one=Y --configfile=/some/file.yml it'll overwrite some-option and another-option values from config file. + if i have validation in those opts.on blocks it won't be applied, no options check is applied either (so i can write some insane values to config). this approach is definitely wrong. i've already tried it.

Comment: @Daniel, I tried to provide a general idea, of course you should modify it to fit your specific needs.

Comment: improving this ends up in extension of OptionParser (adding new parse_file method, which is very looks like OptionParse#parse_in_order), i've almost finished it, but though i'll find something ready for use. If no then i'll finish my implementation and post it somewhere.

Comment: regarding "if i have validation in those opts.on blocks it won't be applied". You are then coupling the options reading with logic business, which is discouraged. Your code should only read the options (optparse or whatever), merge (or reverse_merge, as you need/like) with the options in the configuration file, and then  validate, use, etc. BTW, there are cooler alternatives for optparser, for example: http://trollop.rubyforge.org

Answer (score 2):

Still getting familiar with ruby, but I had to tweak options.merge (to use options.merge!):

```
options.merge!(Hash[YAML::load(open(path)).map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }])
```

to get this to work for me, this is great stuff, definitely appreciate the answers.